# Is there a way to make JSON output in a 2D matrix table?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I've been trying and looking at different things, but I'm stumped.
I tried using a 2D matrix of strings and then to print it out on Spring Boot I made a JSONArray which would represent the the 2D matrix and hold the place.

So here comes my issue.

I create this:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject("{\"Dimensions\":\"[2,2]\"" + matrix + "}");
```

The output is on a single line:
{"Dimensions":"[2,2]"["1","2","3","4"]}

I was wondering if its possible to make it so I could make the JSON print out like a 2 by 2 matrix table so like

```
["1", "2",
 "3", "4",]
```

I know its not proper JSON printout but I was wondering if there were ways to manipulate it? I tried using GSON, Jackson or maybe I used it wrong, not sure. I would love to get some insight if I shouldn't even be approaching it like this or if there was something I missed!

Thanks!

Comment: JSON is a data transfer format. Extract the data out of the JSON, and print it the way you like. Most JSON libraries allow to pretty-print the JSON to make it more readable than a single line, but it won't go further than that. Why do you care about how JSON is printed? Why do you print JSON in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm buildilng a rest service where my GET and POST content type has to be application/json. I care about how its printed because I want the user not to have a headache when he or she is trying to read lets say a 20 by 20 dimension table in a single line.

Comment: Then use pretty-print, or better, let the user pretty-print the JSON the way they want. Browser dev tools do that automatically. So do REST clients. So do most JSON libraries. So do command-line utilities. So do decent text editors.

Comment: I see! Thank you for your the information JB! I do appreciate it. I will let the user handle how they want to see it and I will go about my day without worrying so much about it. Thanks again!